# Python string iteration: how to print any non-vowel chars first, then vowels last (via For loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to return all non-vowel characters first, then vowels **last** from any given string. This is what I have so far, which is printing non-vowels first, but not printing any vowels after:

```
# Python 3
# Split a string: consonants/any-char (1st), then vowels (2nd)

def split_string():
    userInput = input("Type a word here: ")
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for i in userInput:
        if i not in vowels:
            print(i, end="")
            i += i
        # else:
        #     if i in vowels:
        #         print(i, end="")
        #         i = i+i
        # This part does not work, so I commented it out for now!
    return(userInput)
input = split_string()
```

Answered! I simply needed a second loop that is *not* nested inside the first loop.

```
def split_string():
    userInput = input("Type a word here: ")
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for i in userInput:
        if i not in vowels:
            print(i, end="")
            i += i
    for i in userInput:
        if i in vowels:
            print(i, end="")
    return(userInput)

input = split_string()
```

Comment: You need two loops. One for the non-vowels. One for the vowels.

Comment: Thanks, @MateenUlhaq. The second loop (for the vowels) needs to be nested inside the first, correct? That's what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Nope, they should be two separate loops

Comment: Thank you! I got it working by simply adding a second loop inside the function! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idiomatic answer.

```
def group_vowels(word):
    vowels = [x for x in word if x in "aeiou"]
    non_vowels = [x for x in word if x not in "aeiou"]
    return vowels, non_vowels

word = input("Type a word here: ")
vowels, non_vowels = group_vowels(word)
print("".join(non_vowels))
print("".join(vowels))
```

Notice:

- `group_vowels` returns a list of vowels and a list of non-vowels.
- *Either* two lists or two loops are needed to compute the vowels and non_vowels. (In this case, I use *both* two lists and two loops because it looks prettier.)
- No user input within a function (it's better style).
- You can use `join` to concatenate together a list of characters into a single string.